# Put Java array value into an javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, javabeans

I have an array inside Java bean I want to put an array element into Jquery array in order to create autocomplete. I called the Java array on the page and started iterate it and put value in the Jquery array Var, but it is not working, this is my code, please any help, thanks in advance.

First, I start by calling the Java array this is the code

```
<% kurd.org.OntologyManagement kurd=new kurd.org.OntologyManagement(); %>

<% List<String> result = kurd.printINDirect(); %>
```

After that I start writing the Jquery function, this is code for jquery

```
<script>
  $("document").ready(function() {
    var availableTags = [

      //iterate java array         
      <%for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {%>
        <%if(!result.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("owl:nothing")){ %>

          //put value in the var elemnet
          <%=result.get(i)%>,
        <%}
      }%>   

    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Convert to _JSON_ to pass the data, parse the _JSON_ to read the data

Comment: @PaulS. sorry I am quite new in jave I don't know how to convert it into JSON, can you give me some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check this..

```
    var arr = new Array();
    <% for (int j=0; j<arrList.size(); j++) { %>
    arr[<%= j %>] = "<%= arrList.get(j) %>"; 
    <% } %>
```

arrList is a arraylist you can use array for your problem..
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

push() method is used to add value in javascript array.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
var availableTags = [];

  //iterate java array         
  <%for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {%>
    <%if(!result.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("owl:nothing")){ %>

      //put value in the var elemnet
       availableTags.push(<%result.get(i)%>);
    <%}
  }%>   


$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
```